# What does ${$} mean / do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

While learning PowerShell, I executed the command `${$}` by mistake and got an output like this:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> Get-ChildItem Env: | Out-File -FilePath $home\env.txt
PS C:\Users\myuser> ${$}
$home\env.txt
```

First I believed it was something like `$_`, but doing `${$_}` does not behave the same.

As per other samples I tried, it seems to retrieve the last argument from the previous command, but I'm not quite sure how it works or what it is actually doing.

I would appreciate an explanation or link to documentation/explanation.

PowerShell host information, if needed:

> Name             : ConsoleHost
>   Version          : 5.1.17134.858
>   InstanceId       : [Removed as I don't if can be shared careless]
>   UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
>   CurrentCulture   : en-US
>   CurrentUICulture : en-US
>   PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
>   DebuggerEnabled  : True
>   IsRunspacePushed : False
>   Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input `${$}` gets evaluated as the automatic variable `$$`. `$$` itself is set to the last token of the last input line in the session. In your case it is set to the last argument `home\env.txt`

You can see this effect also with input like `${?}` that results in `$?`, another automatic variable, which contains the result of the last executed command.

For a list of automatic variables see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: Awesome !  Haven't read any until know for this "automatic variables", thank you. Now I understand why first google attempt didn't return something useful